# How to link c library in cdt eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to link `libc.a` library but always get `cannot find -llibc`. Library is in project `lib` folder. Below is my linker settings and workspace sreenshots.

Full compilation string:

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -L"/home/kripton/Applications/ARM_workspace/Bell/lib" -T "/home/kripton/Applications/ARM_workspace/Bell/stm32f103.ld" -g3  -ggdb -O0 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd   -Wl,-Map=linker.map -Wl,-cref  -Wl,--gc-sections -o "Bell.elf"  ./stm_startup/startup_stm32f10x_md.o ./stm_startup/system_stm32f10x.o  ./src/main.o ./src/syscalls.o  ./cmsis_core/core_cm3.o   -llibc`

Linker libraries settings:
[image: Linker settings]

As I said `libc.a` placed in project `lib` directory.
[image: Workspace]

**UPDATE**

Problem solved by manually installing newlib and replace all sources and libraries with new.

Comment: To link with libc, you want a switch like -lc, not -llibc.  In the list of libraries, try changing libc to c.

Comment: @SloopJon thanks for your answer. Just tried it, got the same error `cannot find -lc`